# Model gets NULL while passing as parameter from POST method to GET method of same controller in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I was not able to get model and its value in a `GET` method which is passed by `POST` of same controller. Please find the code snippet below. Please help me to resolve it.

Model:

```
public class country
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public long? CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Country _country)
{
    var data = await checkduplicate(_country);

    if (!data.status)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", data.ErrorMessage);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {_country});
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Country _country)
{
    return View("Create", _country);
}
```

In this sample, I have given only two values but actual I have around 8 parameters. Please suggest it. I have used razor view page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls post your whole view that you are trying to submit. Nobody can help you without this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, it was an minor error, while sending the model via post end.
It should be as below. I have included the keyword "new" in it. On removing the keyword new, it is working fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Country _country)
{
    var data = await checkduplicate(_country);

    if (!data.status)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", data.ErrorMessage);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", _country);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```